# Does a system with an infinite number of independent events imply a finite number of cases where no event occurs?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I have the following system:

- An infinite number of sets
- Each set contains an infinite number of positive integers
- The number of sets and the size of each set are all enumerable
- The probability of a positive integer belonging in $S_i$ is $0<P_i<1$
- The probability of a positive integer belonging in $S_i\cap S_j$ is $P_i\cdot P_j$

The meaning of the last bullet is that all events are independent (I believe it implies that all sets, when denoted as strictly-increasing sequences, are linearly-independent, but I'm not 100% sure).

Now, to my understanding, because $\forall{i}:0<P_i<1$, the probability of a positive integer belonging in any of the sets is $1-\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}1-P_i=1$.

Does this imply that there is only a finite number of positive integers which **do not** belong in any of the sets?

I am taking into assumption that:

1. The system described above (and specifically the part about independence) is viable
2. My analysis of the probability of a positive integer belonging in any of the sets being $1$ is correct

Please also let me know if either one of these assumptions is wrong.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @drhab: Yes, sorry, I will fix that

Comment: Pairwise independence is not independence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Then I'd like to update that statement for every intersection of every group of sets.

Comment: Then do it. Don't just comment it, please edit the body of the question.

Comment: Maybe you could do it today, good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select uniformly from a countable set, making your probabilities difficult to interpret directly.  Let's instead suppose you are selecting uniformly from $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,n\}$ where your probabilities and independence are the limit as $n \to \infty$

Then as a counter-example, suppose $S_i$ is the set of composite integers divisible by the $i$th prime $p_i$, so for example $S_1=\{4,6,8,10,\ldots\}$.  This should meet your conditions in a reasonable sense

Then the positive integers not in $\bigcup\limits_i S_i$ are $\{1,2,3,5,7,11,\ldots\}$, i.e. $1$ and the primes, and this is an infinite set representing a limit proportion $0$ of the positive integers

Comment: So is my analysis of the probability of a positive integer belonging in any of the sets being $1-\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}1-P_i=1$ wrong then?

Comment: @goodvibration - I was trying to make two points.  First, you need to do something careful when talking about the probability a random positive integer is in a particular set.  Second, the question *"Does this imply that there is only a finite number of positive integers which do not belong in any of the sets?"* is no, it does not imply that.

Comment: So the statement is true but does not imply... or is it false?

Comment: @goodvibration The statement is sometimes false, as shown in my suggested counter-example

Comment: The statement "the probability of a positive integer belonging in any of the sets is $1-\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}1-P_i=1$" is wrong?

Comment: @goodvibration That depends on whether $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(1-P_i\right)=0$.  An example where it is not would be with $P_i=\frac1{2^i}$ in which case $1- \prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(1-P_i\right) \approx 0.71121$