# How can I prove that these events are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

I have a pair of sets:

- $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid p\cdot n\}$
- $B=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid q\cdot n\}$

Where $p$ and $q$ are two different prime numbers.

And the following event definitions:

- $X_n$: $n\in{A}$
- $Y_n$: $n\in{B}$

Does it follow that the events $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every pair of different primes?

I believe that $P(X_n\land Y_n)=P(X_n)\cdot P(Y_n)=\frac1p\cdot\frac1q$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every pair of different primes, hence the answer is true, but I'm finding it hard to prove this.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Before you can speak of dependence you have to have a probability distribution, but you haven't specified one.

Comment: @lulu: I believe that $P(x\in{A})=\frac{1}{p}$, $P(x\in{B})=\frac{1}{q}$ and $P(x\in{A})\land P(x\in{B})=\frac{1}{qp}$.

Comment: Please use Mathjax.  And it's not a question of what you believe, but of what you define.  What is the sample space?  What is the probability distribution on it?

Comment: @lulu: I thought it was pretty obvious that since we're dealing with sequences, the sample space is $\mathbb{N}$. I can mention that explicitly, but I've figured less text <==> higher level of clarity.

Comment: It's also not a question of what you think is obvious.  There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb N$ so the critical issue is what probability distribution you had in mind.

Comment: @lulu: $x\in\mathbb{N}\implies P(x\in{A})=\frac1p\land P(x\in{B})=\frac1q$. Do you find this satisfying?

Comment: For the $n^{th}$ time, you need to specify  a probability distribution.  What does $P$ mean? One standard thing people do is to first specify an upper bound $N$ and then look at the finite set $(1, \cdots, N)$.  Then you can use the uniform distribution.  Now, you can ask about the limit as $N\to \infty$.  But it's not a good idea to ignore the problem.

Comment: @lulu: OK, I'll rephrase the question with *sets* instead of *sequences*. TX.

Comment: I note that people made exactly the same point in reference to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224205/does-a-system-with-an-infinite-number-of-independent-events-imply-a-finite-numbe).  Please edit your post.

Comment: @lulu: OK, done, Tx.

Comment: Changing the word "sequences" to "sets" has no significance.  I have voted to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  Study the comments and answers you received to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224205/does-a-system-with-an-infinite-number-of-independent-events-imply-a-finite-numbe).  They are addressing the same point I am making.

Comment: @lulu: OK, thanks for nothing, I'll try elsewhere; This website used to be helpful in the past, but I see it's gradually turning into stack overflow...

Answer (score 1):

Since the author doesn't know the probability distribution, I will assume exponential distribution:
$$
P(n=k) = \frac122^{-k}, \qquad k=0,1,2...
$$

With that assumption, $P(X_n)=\frac{1/2}{1-2^{-p}}$, $P(Y_n)=\frac{1/2}{1-2^{-q}}$, $P(X_n\wedge Y_n)=\frac{1/2}{1-2^{-qp}}$. One can see that these events are not independent.

Can one come up with the distribution, so these events are independent? It is quite another story.

Comment: Sure you can.  The limit distribution of the uniform on bounded sets works.  But your point is correct, of course.  The choice of distribution is the critical thing.

Comment: The distribution is uniform, i.e., choose a random positive integer $n$, then $X_n$ is the event $x\in A$ and $Y_n$ is the event $x\in B$. I know that $P(X_n)=\frac1p$ and $P(Y_n)=\frac1q$, and I'm pretty sure that the events are independent, but I'm not sure how to come up with a formal proof.

Comment: @goodvibration  As has been pointed out to you repeatedly, there is no uniform distribution on an infinite set.  That's the entire problem here.

Comment: @lulu: So given the two infinite (but enumerable) sets $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$, I cannot state that when selecting an element from $\mathbb{N}$, the probability of it being in $A$ is well defined (and of course, a value between $0$ and $1$)?

Comment: @goodvibration  No.  Not without saying what you mean by probability.  Infinite sets are complicated. You can't just wave your hands.  That's what everyone has been trying to tell you.

Comment: @goodvibration, maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255667/prove-there-exists-no-uniform-distribution-on-a-countable-and-infinite-set) will be a good explanation of why there is no uniform distribution on countable infinite sets.